# Fixing an inwall toilet constantly flowing

Tags: toilet, cistern

I have a Schwab inwall toilet. Water keeps flowing heavily after flushing.

I took everything out of the wall and found that the reason is because the ?hammer doesn't come back up again, therefore the ?float never thinks that it is full.

The reason it doesn't come up is because the plastic is 'squeaking' where the red circle is in my image.

[image]

What I really want to know is whether I have to replace that bit or if there is a way I can loosen it a bit. And if I do have to replace, then which part and what is it called.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently that joint is wearing out. You may have to replace the whole assembly. The wonders of modern plastic.

As a stop-gap I would try greasing it (not oiling it). With silicone grease. Petroleum products and plastic don't play well together.

Comment: Thank you. Used petroleum jelly and that seemed to do the trick. Also detached the blue from the white hammer, and the extra few millimeters may have meant that it didn't have to be pushed up anymore. All is good.